# How to validate query parameters in Reform::Form in Trailblazer?

Tags: ruby, validation, reform

I am working on a GET API using Trailblazer which receives a list of comma separated list of numeric ids. 
`desired-path?page_number=4&ids=765,359249,4011`
How can I validate through Reform::Form that the ids query parameter has only integers in it

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are on `dry-validation` version `0.x` or above. The name of your parameter leads me to believe that:

- it is not backed by a model
- it is not required

For these reasons, validate with `optional` and annotate the property with `virtual: true` (relevant docs [here](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/0.13/optional-keys-and-values/), [here](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/rules/#checking-if-the-value-is-present) and [here](http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform/options.html#virtual-attributes)):

```
class MyContract < Reform::Form
  property :ids, virtual: true

  validation do
    # for 0.x:
    #   optional(:ids).each(:int?)
    # for 1.x:
    optional(:ids).array(:integer)
  end
end
```

Documentation on validating array input on version `0.x` is [here](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/0.13/basics/macros/#each) and the same for `1.x` is [here](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/rules/#defining-a-rule-for-each-element-of-an-array).